# Is there a I/O completion port based component for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, iocp

I am aware of [Indy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Direct), [ICS](http://www.vclcomponents.com/Delphi/Winsock___Internet/ICS__Internet_Component_Suite-info.html), [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/about) and [Clever InetSuite](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/inetsuite/suite.asp), none of which support [IOCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output_completion_port). Is there anything else out there?

Edit:
I found [iocpclasses](http://iocpclasses.sourceforge.net/) , It's written in Delphi5. Better than nothing I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check http://voipobjects.com/index.php?page=delphi-iocp-library
It is migrated iocpclasses.sourceforge.net (i'm an author).
Enjoy :)

Update: voipobjects has not dedicated page for this library.
It lives here https://bitbucket.org/voipobjects/iocpengine.

Update 2: bitbucket doesn't offer Mercurial anymore, so I moved to gitlab.
https://gitlab.com/dmytro.bogovych/iocpengine

Comment: The linked page is not available. Could you update your post, please ? Thanks! [+1]

Answer (score 6):

Indy 10 has experimental support for fibers and IOCP:

From [Indy knowledge base](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=WhatsNewIndy10.html):

> Indy 10 provides experimental support
>   for the Fiber and I/O Completion Ports
>   API in the Windows platforms. This
>   support is designed to aid in creating
>   more scalable servers where thousands
>   of simultaneous client connections are
>   required. For small- and medium-sized
>   projects, the traditional thread-based
>   servers are still available.
>
> Fiber and IOCP APIs are supported only
>   for the Windows 2000, 2003, and XP
>   operating systems using Delphi version
>   7. Windows 95, 98, and ME are not supported. Delphi compilers prior to
>   version 7 are also unsupported due to
>   critical changes in the VCL since
>   those releases.

This is not installed by default, and I haven't used it myself, so I am not sure how much usable it is. I guess you need to download the latest SVN revision from their repository to use this experimental feature.

Using it must be straightforward; you create a IdTcpServer instance, and instead of the default scheduler, you use the scheduler class which provides IOCP support. The rest should be considered internal work of the provided scheduler class.

Comment: Just to complete @Arnaud's question, no [Indy does not have any IOCP capabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924616/how-to-listen-1200-devices/15927999#comment22693455_15927999).

Answer (score 5):

[Synopse mORMot and SynCrtSock](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki/Synopse+OpenSource)
and
[DWScript's HttpSys2WebServer](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/)
both have an IOCP-based server.

Synopse actually has two servers using IOCP, one via http.sys another via sockets.

Answer (score 4):

Not a component but an example: TISAPIThreadPool in ISAPIThreadPool unit.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at **High performance socket server based on Windows Completion Port and with using Windows Socket Extensions. IPv6 supported.**
Link: http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=7131

Answer (score 3):

There is an IOCPPool example for Synapse availabile in the [contributed files](http://synapse.ararat.cz/files/contrib/) section.

Answer (score 2):

There is a project which is based on the former iopcclasses project.

It claims to handle **thousands simultaneous connections**:

> IOCP engine is set of classes, components and routines for rapid
>   creation high scalable and performance TCP/UDP applications.
>   Application created using IOCP classes can handle thousands
>   simultaneous connections.
>
> Library is written in Delphi - Delphi 7 - 2010 are supported.
>
> Library uses IO completion ports technology. There is most powerful
>   technology in Win32 world for creation highly scalable and performance
>   TCP/UDP applications. This technology is supported in all desktop
>   Windows OSes except old Win9x/WinME versions.
>
> This library is licensed under MPL1.1. Also It includes some files
>   from Jedi project (Winsock2 header translation).
>
> https://bitbucket.org/voipobjects/iocpengine

Answer (score 1):

[iocp-delphi](https://github.com/tondrej/iocp-delphi) by Ondrej Kelle who is also the author of chakracore-delphi