# Download and Parse Mail with POP3 (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, email, client, attachment, pop3

I tried to use Indy9 with D6 but I got integer overflow error on parsing the message.

Because of that I search for an active component family for:

- Connect to a server
- Download messages
- Delete downloaded messages
- Parse mails
- Save attachments to files

If there is no other components for Delphi, may I can use c# code (I call a subprocess from the Delphi code).

Thanks for your help:
  dd

Comment: Pick one from this SO question: [Wiki: Current state of the art of Delphi 3rd party TCP/IP components libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5709127/282676).

Comment: Also: are you sure the Indy code was to blame? I've used Indy for POP3 myself and I know many other used it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to install a newer version of Indy (which one are you using?), some releases are known to be buggy, I remember I had to apply a patch from the newsgroup to make the message parsing code to work fully for a while - which error are you getting? Alternative are [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download) (less "visual"), or [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html)

Anyway, whatever internet protocol (POP, IMAP) you use to get mail, it is in RFC(2)822 format, its format does not depend from the mailbox handling protocol, or the protocol used to send it (SMTP).

Comment: I used the last stable "indy9.0.18_source", but this buggy on parsing the mail I got. ICS isn't compilable under Delphi 6. Can I parse the mail body with Synapse? The most problem is to parse it.

Comment: Indy 9.0.18 is old now and has known bugs, some in the message parsing code . Indy still supports D6, I'd switch to a more recent vesion from here: http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/DevSnapshot.EN.aspx - "stable" builds of Indy are usually outdated and sometimes buggy. Indy 10 is somewhat better, but is not fully backward compatible. Synapse has message handling functions (see class TMimeMess), although I am not sure it is as comprehensive as the Indy one.